# Assigning Binary Values to duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, binary, duplicates, teradata

I have the following table

```
Animal 
dog
dog
dog
cat
cat
```

I want to run a query that exports the following by assigning binary values.

```
Animal Unique
dog    1
dog    0
dog    0
cat    1
cat    0
```

I tried using row_number over partition but I need subsequent values to be zero.

I need this as it will be connected to power query and a pivot table in which I want to sum the column so the I see the unique count of animals

Comment: which dbms are you using? there is no `row_number() over()` in mysql/

Comment: You have and id ( row id pk) in your table ?

Comment: Sorry,  I updated my tag.  I inadvertently selected "MySQL", I am using Teradata.

Also, the table does not have a PK in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the odd table design, you can use rows preceeding to do this. Basically, if the animal in the current row = the animal in the preceding row, set it to 0, otherwise set it to 1.

```
    create multiset  volatile table vt (animal varchar(10))
    on commit preserve rows;
    insert into vt values ( 'cat'  );

    select 
    animal,
    case when max(animal) over (partition by animal order by animal 
    rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) = animal then 0 else 1 end as test
    from vt order by animal, test desc
```

Which will give you:

```
cat 1
cat 0
dog 1
dog 0
dog 0
```

Comment: I was able to use 'case when max(animal) over (partition by animal order by animal 
    rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) = animal then 0 else 1 end as test
' without creating the volatile table and it worked!...Thanks! :)  Also, the answer posted by "dnoeth" was also correct, but this one was posted first.

Answer (score 1):

You were close using `row_number`, just use a `case`:

```
select animal,
   case when row_number() 
             over (partition by animal order by animal) = 1 
        then 1 
        else 0 
   end
from t1
```

Comment: Thanks!  this worked! Unfortunately, I can only select one correct answer and Andrew posted first :(

Comment: @AlmostThere: You can accept only one answer, but you might upvote multiple, of course you should upvote Andrew's, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not at all pretty but it works...

```
Select fullList.Animal, case when mr is not null then 1 else 0 end as uniq from 
  (SELECT min(rank) mr, animal
  FROM (SELECT A.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
      FROM t1 A
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      ORDER BY ANIMAL) B
  GROUP BY ANIMAL) SubSet
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT A.*, @rwnum := @rwnum + 1 AS rank
      FROM t1 A
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rwnum := 0) r
      ORDER BY ANIMAL) FullList
on FullList.Animal = SubSet.Animal
and FullList.Rank = SubSet.mr
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc5386/13/0

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and sorry for the inconvenience I caused by posting MYSQL.